# Angular js filter an array of objects based on values in another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have to filter an array of objects based on some preferences.

The Array I need to filter looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "book",
      "name": "test"
   },
   {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "book2",
      "name": "test2"
   }
]
```

The preferences look like this:

```
[
   {
      'type': ["book", "book3"]
   }
]
```

The filter should return all objects that matches the value of the preferences. So the desired result should be:

```
[
   {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "book",
      "name": "test"
   }
]
```

I have tried to use the following function from the example I found here:

```
const filtered = products.filter(a => this.preferences.some(b => {
      b.type == a.type
    } 
));
```

However, I am not getting the response I am expected with this sample code.

2nd question:

Here is a new preference:

```
[
   {
      'type': ["book", "book3"]
   }, {

      'name': ["test"]
   }
]
```

second object is optional, how do I filter using this new preference?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const filtered = products.filter(a => this.preferences.some(b => {
  return b.type.indexOf(a.type) > -1
} 
));
```

You try to check if array equals string so it will never return true

**UPD for the 2nd question**

If you need more flexible code you can write something like this for 1 or more preferences.

```
const filtered = products.filter(a => {
  // total matches for all preferences
  let matches = 0;

  this.preferences.forEach(b => {
    // local match for a preference
    let prefMatches = 0;

    // iterate all preference keys for calculating local preference match
    const bKeys = Object.keys(b);
    bKeys.forEach(key => {
      if (b[key].indexOf(a[key]) > -1) {
        prefMatches += 1;
      }
    });

    if (prefMatches === bKeys.length) {
      matches += 1;
    }
  });
  
  // so all preferences must match or it returns false 
  return matches === this.preferences.length;
});
```

If you want at least 1 match you can rewrite it like:

```
const filtered = products.filter(a => {
  this.preferences.forEach(b => {
    // local match for a preference
    let prefMatches = 0;

    // iterate all preference keys for calculating local preference match
    const bKeys = Object.keys(b);
    bKeys.forEach(key => {
      if (b[key].indexOf(a[key]) > -1) {
        prefMatches += 1;
      }
    });

    // so at least one preference must match
    if (prefMatches === bKeys.length) {
      return true;
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works. How about if I have multiple data in preferences, similar to New preference?

Comment: @user20256558 Answered, check above